# Create a trigger update a field in a table from Total of Line Items in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two table Order and Order_Details. I would like to create a trigger that would update the Order.Order_Total by adding the Order_Details.Price fields that belong to that specific order. Here's what I have so far but its giving me the following error 
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

```
Update Order
Set Order_Total = 
    (Select SUM(Price)
    From Order_Details
    Group By Order_Id)
From Order_Details
```

Comment: It's usually best not to *store* that which can be *calculated*. Unless performance is critical, all you do by doing so is open up the opportunity for the calculated value to get out of sync with reality (e.g. someone prevents your trigger from running temporarily). Whereas if you calculate during data retrieval, you know that the value produced is consistent with the rest of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. The issue is in your sub query which does not have any binding with the order table.

```
UPDATE o
  SET o.Order_Total = t.tprice
FROM Order o
            LEFT JOIN ( SELECT Order_Id, SUM(isnull(price,0)) tprice 
                               FROM OrderDetails
                               GROUP BY Order_Id) t
                         ON o.Order_Id=t.Order_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's what I ended up doing in case someone has the same question. I created a CTE to add the Order_Details price and I updated the Order.Total from that CTE. Here's the full code I used.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = object_id('dbo.trOrder_Details_AIU') ) 
  DROP TRIGGER dbo.trOrder_Details_AIU
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trOrder_Details_AIU
   ON  dbo.Order_Details
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE, Delete
AS 
BEGIN
    set nocount on;
    begin 
    ; with Total_CTE(Order_Id, Total)
    as 
    ( 
        Select Order_Id, SUM(Price)
        From Order_Details 
            Group By Order_Id
    )

Update Order
Set Order_Total = Total_CTE.Amount
From Total_CTE
Where Total_CTE.Order_Id = Total.Order_Id
    end
END
```

Comment: This will not scale well. You're recalculating the totals for *all* orders even if a particular statement only involved a single order. Any trigger that fails to use `inserted` or `deleted` (as here) is probably quite broken.